# Reading a file with multi pickled items from the end

Tags: python, pickle

I am saving information to a file using the pickle.dump function in Python 3.4. I am trying to read the data in LIFO (last in first out) form.

Alternative, I am thinking maybe there is a way I could just read the last item, assuming there is a way to point to it directly. Then point to it again and remove it from the file before reading the next item.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you written something that we could try improving ? Also, are you trying to avoid reading the whole file into memory ("just read the last item") ?

Comment: Sorry but I haven't written anything yet because I can't figure out away of reaching the last item without actually going through the entire file.

Comment: You'd have to maintain an index of the file position where each pickle started, perhaps in a second file.

Comment: There is no other way to just point directly to the last item in the file? Because your suggestion would mean that every time I am adding an item to the file I have to read the index file entirely and write it again or add an item to that file at the end, which does not seem to be much more efficient than reading the entire pickled file unless the object file holds very large objects.

Comment: of course not, unless you happen to know the length of all previous items...

Comment: Can one add an item to the beginning of the file then instead of its end?

Comment: only if you're willing to rewrite the whole file each time.... - aka. not nice - use something else than a file, and why pickle in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the indices of the items and read them in a new order:

```
import pickle
data = ["this", "is", "your", "data"]
indices = [] # keep the index
with open("file_name.p", "wb") as f:
    for value in data:
        indices.append(f.tell())
        pickle.dump(value, f)

# you may want to store `indices` to files
# and read it in again
new_data = []
with open("file_name.p", "rb") as f:
    for ap in indices[::-1]:
        f.seek(ap)
        new_data.append(pickle.load(f))
print(new_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It does seems to work. I have only one concern, because I need to be able to do that after losing power etc. Saving the indices to a file would mean to load, append and save after every pickle.dump?

Comment: Yes. It's just a list, so you can also save it to a pickle file, and update it when you do pickle.dump.